# Iterable's whereType method behaviour

Tags: dart, flutter

I am having problem with understanding how `iterable`'s `whereType` works.

I have following example and I have no idea why it is behaving this way. Having this code:

```
List<dynamic> list = ["SomeString", 12];
print(list);
print(list.whereType<String>());
print(list.where((item) => item is String));
```

The output is:

```
[SomeString, 12]
(SomeString, 12)
(SomeString)
```

I would expect only String in second print. Could someone explain to me why I am wrong?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me, but also seems to have something to do with the generic templating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an inconsistency because `whereType` is designed for Dart2 but Dart2 is not complete.

There is an open issue that looks similar

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32423

```
dart --reify-generic-functions my_script.dart
```

should make it work

Comment: This is correct. Dart 1 does not implement generic methods, it merely allows the syntax (for forward compatibility) and treats all arguments as `dynamic`. In this case, you get the result of `list.whereType<dynamic>()`, which isn't what you wanted, but it can't actually work until Dart 2 behavior is enabled.